# Time jumping on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I use this simple logging approach in my python app on Raspberry Pi Zero W:

```
import logging

def get_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if not logger.handlers:
        log_handler = logging.FileHandler(config.LOG[name]["FILE"])
        log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
        logger.addHandler(log_handler)
        logger.setLevel(config.LOG[name]["LEVEL"])
    return logger

logger = get_logger('MAIN')
logger.info('text')
```

This Python app is ran automatically at boot. Today I had brief battery failure for a few milliseconds and the Pi rebooted. When I checked the log file, I discovered a strange thing - the log entries after reboot appeared in the log file with "older" timestamp:

```
2019-09-10 06:17:58,739 INFO event before reboot
2019-09-10 06:17:58,763 INFO event before reboot
2019-09-10 06:20:48,771 INFO event before reboot
2019-09-10 06:20:48,794 INFO event before reboot
2019-09-10 06:17:30,302 INFO event after reboot
2019-09-10 06:17:30,307 INFO event after reboot
```

I wonder what might cause such behaviour, and how to fix it. My primary speculation would be that Pi launches at boot some time-adjustment utility that updates the system clock. And that in my particular case, that resulted in clock being wound a bit back. But I don't know if there is any way to verify this hunch.

Comment: This is likely neither a Python nor a Raspberry Pi thing, but an OS thing (probably an NTP sync on boot).  With that: (1) please tell us which OS you're running; (2) the question is likely better suited for either http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @NPE The OS is Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), Lite

Comment: Might be possible that your raspi has no internal RTC-Module.. so it got reset and loaded the last saved timestamp. Then it wrote your logfile before it was abled to connect to the internet for catching the current time. You might enable, that your raspi only boots when it's connected to the internet to minimize this issue.

Comment: @EirikFesker I think your guess is right. I had no idea Pi doesn't have onboard clock. I have disabled the NTP service now. In my case, I am better off with incorrect time than with time jumping around while the app runs, making scheduled task execution unreliable.